# Setting PHPSESSID Cookie, CORS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I execute `$.ajax` call to query primary *host1* from *host2*.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: host2` header is sent on *host1*.

**The problem**: I need to be authenticated, but PHP Session is not set for *host1* because of CORS.

**Question**: Do I need to extract PHPSESSID Set-Cookie header returned from *host1* and set it back to the same host, *host1*?

```
// On Host2
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://Host1/User/Login/',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Id:Id,UserName:UserName},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Your host1 need to set the property in response header like that.

Comment: As you see, it is set: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: host2. I didn't use wildcard, but hostname.

Comment: if your problem hasn't solved, try to add this after line above. 
hope this help !

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");`